# sql matching in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, match, fuzzy

I have two tables that I am trying to match on column from each.  The columns on each table are names and have been standardized as best as I can.  Even though standardized the two columns are not exactly the same and I need to match the table together based off these columns.

I have done an InStr function, but that is not ok with my boss.  And an inner join is not alright either.  I am at a loss trying to find a third way to do this.

Column in Table 1 - 
Jimmy Johns Sandwiches

Column in Table 2 - 
Jimmy John

I need a formula that would capture a match and join the tables based on this example.  I know InStr can do this for me, but I need a different way.

Comment: Both tables are quite large and so I cannot simply do a 'text-to-column' based on 'space' in excel for each column and then join off of the newly created first column of each table.  The matches would be too many and too inaccurate taking that route.  -cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing you can try is using like operator.

something like:
table1.column like "*"&table2.column&"*"

like operator reference
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have actually tried that option with the wildcards, but the matching does not appear to be working at being discerning enough. Within Access, my criteria on the Like statement is this: Like "[sheet2.columnB]*"  This results in matches that should not be matches.

Comment: Oh boy, looks like you have found my error!  Like ""&[sheet1.columnb]&"*"  seems to have worked.